# Query data on firebase for web

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm building a music platform, using firebase, where users can upload their songs. When a user logs in, I save their data on the "usuarios" node. And when they upload a song, I push to the "musicas" node (child of usuarios). 
This way, I know who uploaded the song.

But the problem is: I want to get a list of all the last 15 songs uploaded. How do I do that? Did I structure my data wrong?

Here's what I tried:

```
  var musicsRef = firebase.database().ref('usuarios').orderByChild('musicas');
  musicsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.child('musicas');
});
```

Here's my database structured:[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Firebase (like with most NoSQL databases) you often end up modeling your data for the way you app wants to consume it. So if you need to find a global list of the most recently uploaded songs, you should keep such a list:

```
songsByDate
  $pushIdOfSong: true
```

You'll note that we don't keep a real value in this list. It is just the ID of each song and a `true` value. This is called a secondary index and so command that we [explain it in our documentation on creating a scalable data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout).

With that structure in place you can query with:

```
var recents = ref.child('songsByDate').orderByKey().limitToLast(15);
recents.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var key = snapshot.key;
  // load the song by its key
});
```

I highly recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).